# PHP (Laravel) Dependency Injection Basics

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have recently come across the SOLID design principles and have been looking to find ways to incorporate dependency injection into my work so that I can write better tests and mock out any external calls. I have had a go at some dependency injection in PHP Laravel (Lumen) but something doesn't seem right in the below.

The code to create the dependencies is being created inside a public method in one of the controllers. This doesn't seem like the appropriate place to put it as I now have a lot of quite ugly code instantiating objects inside the controller rather than just receiving the request and packaging up the response. Is there somewhere more appropriate to the do the instantiation? Also for certain items, e.g. the `$paying_user object`. I am creating an empty Eloquent model, using a method to retrieve the first item in a collection and swapping it with the returned object to inject. This doesn't feel right either. Can anyone point me in what the best and proper way to structure the below should be?

```
public function cancel_subscription(Request $request)
{
    $result = false;

    // Create dependencies
    $platform_id = Sanitiser::clean_integer($request->input('platform_id'));
    $paying_user = new PayingUserModel();
    $paying_user = $paying_user->where('platform_id','=',$platform_id)->first();
    $current_subscription_model = $paying_user->non_cancelled_subscriptions->first();
    $refund_model = new RefundModel();
    $stripe = new Stripe();
    $stripe_refund = new Refund();
    $charge = new ChargeModel();
    $stripe::setAPIkey(env('STRIPE_SK'));
    $stripe_subscription = new Subscription();

    // Create services and inject
    $this->cancellation_service = new CancellationService($paying_user,$current_subscription_model,$stripe_subscription);
    $this->refund_service = new RefundService($paying_user,$current_subscription_model,$refund_model,$stripe_refund,$charge);

    // Run services
    $result = $this->cancellation_service->cancel_subscription();
    if($this->cancellation_service->get_refund_required()==true){
        $result = $this->refund_service->handle_refund();
    }
}
```

Comment: "the $paying_user object below it is swapped with an actual paying user object before being injected" ... what?

Comment: $paying_user = new PayingUserModel();
$paying_user = $paying_user->where('platform_id','=',$platform_id)->first()    //trying to say that I'm creating an empty Eloquent Model,  using it to retrieve the first item of a collection (to get the actual data) for the model I want to inject into my other classes.

Comment: the "... before being injected" part ... there is no 'injection' happening when you are calling methods or instantiating objects yourself

Comment: You are doing too much inside one method in Controller, at first you should separate the concerns in different type of objects/different places.

Comment: If I split the method and moved the refund activities to a new method, would the controller still be the most appropriate place to instantiate these empty objects and inject into the other objects?

Comment: @lagbox even if he technically isn't doing Laravel injecting he still obvi has a valid concern - he is instantiating a lot of classes in one controller and not separating his concerns. OP could consider the Repository pattern.

Comment: I would use a Repository pattern, move the models away from the Controller and into the Repositories so that you aren't making such a bulky controller. Think of the controller as an extension of the router, it points to what functionality you want but it shouldn't try to spell out that functionality.

Comment: @lagbox I think the OP knows the difference, `$this->cancellation_service` looks like a potential injection while he mentions `instantiation` in his question.

Comment: @lagbox oh gotcha, yes if OP means the service arguements then in that case that is not the same as injecting. i thought you were referring to his entire post not that specific comment.

Comment: @lagbox maybe not tho haha - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232229/understanding-dependency-injection - I suppose you are differentiating between what in Laravel is termed `DI` vs passing an arguement

Comment: Have you looked intro Laravel [service containers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container)? I always look into it when I have doubts about how to manage my class dependencies.

Comment: OP, the best thing to do in your case is look at successful Laravel projects and how they accomplish this, again, with Repos. The service container docs are nice, but they are more high-level. Look at this for example: https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate

Comment: You can type-hint method arguments and Laravel will try to resolve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well, you are trying to organize your code using dependency injection. I think the easiest way to do it, is by using Laravel's automatic injection.

Looking at your code, the class where `cancel_subscription()` is defined, depends of `CancellationService` and `RefundService`.

At the same time `CancellationService` depends of `PayingUserModel` and `Subscription`. And `RefundService` depends of `PayingUserModel`, `RefundModel`, `Refund` and `ChargeModel`.

You can use automatic injection by type hinting the arguments in each class constructor.

E.g. the `CancellationService` class constructor would look something like:

```
class CancellationService
{
    protected $payingUserModel;

    protected $subscription;

    public function __construct(PayingUserModel $payingUserModel, Subscription $subscription)
    {
        $this->payingUserModel = $payingUserModel;

        $this->subscription = $subscription;
    }
}
```

Now, for the `PayingUserModel` you want to pass a specific instance of the class.

This can be done by binding an instance to the container in the `AppServiceProvider` class.

```
$platform_id = request()->input('platform_id');

$user = PayingUserModel::where('platform_id', '=', $platform_id)->first();

$this->app->instance('PayingUserModel', $user);
```

Alternatively you could register the `PayingUserModel` instance as a singleton.

```
$this->app->singleton('PayingUserModel', function() use($platform_id) {
    return PayingUserModel::where('platform_id', '=', $platform_id)->first();
});
```

I didn't try it myself so I'm not 100% sure if this is the way to go. But according to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#introduction) this is how you manage dependency injection and hopefully it will give you an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks Camilo, I've managed to implement something very close to the recommendation.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Took me some time to understand the question and come up with a suggestion.